# How to make a clear icon in Excel Ribbon?

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I made an icon for my Excel add-in `Bottleneck Detector`. The following is the first version:

[image: Excel ribbon with blurry custom icon]

As you can see, my icon on the right is not as clear as the existing icons in Excel.

When uploading an add-in, The manifest file requires the icon of several pixel sizes for different purposes: [16x16](http://www.matrixlead.com/bottleneck-1.0/images/logo16x16.png), [32x32](http://www.matrixlead.com/bottleneck-1.0/images/logo32x32.png), [64x64](http://www.matrixlead.com/bottleneck-1.0/images/logo64x64.png), [80x80](http://www.matrixlead.com/bottleneck-1.0/images/logo80x80.png), [96x96](http://www.matrixlead.com/bottleneck-1.0/images/logo96x96.png). Initially, I made an icon of `300x300` in `PhotoShop`, resized it to different sizes. In testing, I realized that the icon in the image is the `32x32` one. Here's the relevant excerpt from my manifest file:

```
<Hosts>
  <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
  ...
      <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
      </Icon>
  ...    
<Resources>
  <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue=".../images/logo32x32.png" />
    ...
</Resources>
```

I also asked someone to do a same `32x32` `vector` icon in `illustrator`, but it is still blurry in Ribbon.

So, my first doubt is... do we have to use the `32x32` icon in Ribbon?

If we have to do so, how can I improve the clearness or resolution of that icon? Is there anything I can do in the whole process to make it look clearer?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot somewhere at 100%? The screenshot you posted appears to be enlarged slightly, making it more difficult to tell whether there's a problem.

Comment: You are right, Stack Overflow changed it a little bit, here is a [raw file of the screenshot](http://pastebin.com/raw/fw4RYXa0).

Comment: Thanks - that gave me the solution to the problem - you're at 150% zoom. Full answer added below.

Comment: (Added your improved screenshot to the question to make it clearer for future visitors)

Comment: I know this is meant for commens but I have a question for you. How do you manage to add a button to the Home tab? My ribbon always appears as a new tab when loaded by Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally Office uses the 32x32 icon in the ribbon.

The reason that it looks blurry for you is that on your machine you're using 150% windows zoom (Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display), so in this case Office is displaying an icon that's 50% larger (in each dimension), which is 32 * 1.5 = 48 pixels. Since there's no 48-pixel image available for your add-in, Office is scaling one of the other icons to 48 pixels.

In order to make the button look clear, add a 48x48 icon reference in your manifest. 150% enlargement is quite common on Windows.

-Michael Saunders, PM for Office add-ins

Comment: Indeed, I'm using 150% zoom (17-inch (1920 x 1200) and windows running on a Virtual Machine). Besides the size, other people say if the design is simpler, with more contrast, it will look clearer...

Comment: When I assign my 80px images to the 32px reference, the images show up noticeably sharper. Perhaps it's better at scaling down than up?